# How to update InputSelect source

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have an InputSelect control on my component, and I need to repopulate it on the fly. I.e. repopulate a list of states/provinces based on the selected country. Here is the code:

```
            <InputSelect id="shippingAddressState" @bind-Value="AddressModel.State" class="form-control selectpicker mx-2">
                <option value="">--Select State--</option>

                @foreach (SharedLibrary.Models.StateProvince state in States)
                {
                    <option value="@state.IsoCode">@state.Name</option>
                }
            </InputSelect>
```

In code behind:

```
    [Parameter]
    public List<StateProvince> States { get; set; } = new List<StateProvince>();
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<List<StateProvince>> StatesChanged { get; set; }
    ...
        States = await JsonGetter.GetConcreteResult<List<StateProvince>>(stateProvinceUrl);
        await StatesChanged.InvokeAsync(States);
```

but nothing changes in the dropdown. What am I missing? All I could find so far is about binding the selected value, but not the source of the dropdown...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to call StateHasChanged() manually like this:

```
        States = await ConcreteHttpResultGetter.GetConcreteResult<List<StateProvince>>(stateProvinceUrl);
        StateHasChanged();
```

This refreshes the component.